# What is a channel?

Tags: system-calls

http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html In that reference about system calls, appears a function called dup(). It is said that it duplicates channels. Then my question is, what is a channel?

Comment: From earlier on the same page under the heading _"File Structure Related System Calls"_: _"A channel is a connection between a process and a file that appears to the process as an unformatted stream of bytes"_, i.e. this includes regular files, but also [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), [pipes](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html), [FIFOs](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html) etc.

Comment: Omg sorry, I was reading kind of diagonal because I have an absolutely ridiculous volume of material to learn now... Thank you very much. May you post it as an answer?

Comment: Happy to oblige. Added the quote as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the term *channel* is explained earlier on the [same page](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html) under the heading *"File Structure Related System Calls"*:

> A channel is a connection between a process and a file that appears to the process as an unformatted stream of bytes

As in Unix [*"Everything is a file"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), this includes [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to regular files, but also [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_socket) [kinds of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_socket) [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), [FIFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) etc.